# Vulkan Wayland hangs on vkCmdBeginRenderPass

Tags: linux, vulkan, wayland

I'm trying the Vulkan tutorial on Wayland. I'm following this turorial: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction

It is a port of wayland-egl and OpenGL ES 3 to Vulkan. Every steps fine but I have a trouble in final draw frame function.

In recording command buffer, calling `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` function not returns just blocked.

This is my entire source code.

https://github.com/hardboiled65/WaylandClient-tutorials/blob/947ab7e70740d1be5996350b164ee442fc922370/vulkan/main.c

Sorry but code is too long so I can't submit the question with the code.
Please ignore image loading function and wl_output listener.
What I want to do is just draw triangle to the wayland surface.

I'm searched with this keyword but couldn't found.

Is there something wrong? Why program hangs on `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`.

Comment: In such a case I take some working "hello triangle" code, and step by step transform it to what i desire. That helps to localize the problem and find the answer.

Comment: I misunderstood Vulkan API and C. All the causes were in uninitialized structs. Many Vk_CreateInfo structs has unused flags and pNext fields. But I forgot to initialize it to 0 and NULL. I filled these all fields to zero or NULL, finally my program runs!